# Produce a 404 error when a domain isn't set up (WHM/CentOS)

Tags: php, seo, centos, http-status-code-404, whm

I'm using WHM/cPanel on a CentOS Linux box. When a user types a random sub-domain which does not exist (blahblahblah.mysite.com), they are redirected to defaultwebpage.cgi which has a 200 response header. This is causing SEO issues, is there a way to give a 404 response instead?

Comment: I cant imagine what SEO problems you refer to. google does not make up domain names to crawl. if its not linked to on a site or submitted directly google will never crawl your 'random domain'

Comment: We had some dodgy old subdomains which we needed to remove but had trouble getting a 404 response from those domains after they were deleted from cPanel.

Comment: then those should return 404 and google will remove them.

Comment: Not in my case. The deleted domains continued to redirect to defaultwebpage.cgi with a 200 header for days until I implemented the below solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHM does have a place where you can edit the the *defaultwebpage.cgi* page at *Account Functions > Web Template Editor*. This allows you to change the appearance of the page but because it's HTML you can't give a 404 header response code.

My solution was to go a step higher and find the file causing the redirect in the first place and have that file produce a 404 response instead of redirecting to *defaultwebpage.cgi*.

1. SSH into your server
2. Browse to your htdocs directory: `cd /usr/local/apache/htdocs/`
3. Rename the index file to a PHP file: `mv index.html index.php`
4. Edit the index file: `sudo nano index.php`
5. Replace the contents with: `<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>`
6. Save the file: <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd>
7. Close the file: <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd>

Now when a site cannot be found on the server it loads /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.php which returns a 404 header and no content. You can of course add a custom message inside index.php too if you like but for my purposes a blank page was fine.